# How to access the items inside a list of query sets in django?

Tags: python, django, list, django-queryset

I have to display MULTIPLE posts from MULTIPLE users that the logged in user is currently following on a single page using the django templates. This is the function I've written:

```
def following(request, userName):
    userProfiles = FollowingList.objects.filter(listOwner = request.user)
    print("userProfile is ", userProfiles)
    
    listOfAllPosts = []

    #get posts against following
    for uP in userProfiles:
        getPosts = Posts.objects.filter(created_by = uP.followingID)
        print("Value of getPosts is", getPosts)


        for i in getPosts:
            listOfAllPosts.append(getPosts.values('created_by', 'postContent', 'dateAndTime'))

        print("Printing ALL posts", listOfAllPosts)
    return render(request, "network/following.html", {
            "listOfAllPosts" : listOfAllPosts
            })
```

The result I get from the listOfAllPosts looks like this:

```
 [<QuerySet [{'created_by': 12, 'postContent': 'I have hot air balloon rides', 'dateAndTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 30, 4, 21, 3, 192704, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 
{'created_by': 12, 'postContent': 'adding second post', 'dateAndTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 7, 2, 51, 734510, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]>, 
<QuerySet [{'created_by': 11, 'postContent': 'Hello Sifaah', 'dateAndTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 30, 4, 4, 31, 410825, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]>]
```

However, I want the result to look like this so I can easily print it on the HTML page:

```
[<QuerySet[{'created_by': 12, 'postContent': 'I have hot air balloon rides', 'dateAndTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 30, 4, 21, 3, 192704, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 
{'created_by': 12, 'postContent': 'adding second post', 'dateAndTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 2, 1, 7, 2, 51, 734510, tzinfo=<UTC>)}, 
{'created_by': 11, 'postContent': 'Hello Sifaah', 'dateAndTime': datetime.datetime(2021, 1, 30, 4, 4, 31, 410825, tzinfo=<UTC>)}]>]
```

**Is there a way to achieve this?**

Comment: You just want to print the whole queryset as a string on your html page?

Comment: In your loop `for i in getPosts:` why are you appending the same queryset to the list again and again? did you want to append `i`?

Answer (score 0):

If you put something like this in your following.html file

```html
{% for users_posts in listOfAllPosts %}
    {% for post in users_posts %}
        <p>{{ post }}</p>
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

You will get a result that looks like this on your page.

[image: query string]

If you instead put something like this in your following.html file

```html
{% for users_posts in listOfAllPosts %}
    {% for post in users_posts %}
        <p>Created By: {{ post.created_by }}</p>
        <p>Post Content: {{ post.postContent }}</p>
        <p>Date: {{ post.dateAndTime }}</p>
    {% endfor %} 
{% endfor %}
```

You will get a result that looks like this instead.

[image: formatted posts]

Comment: No problem. Glad I could help!